# RxJava debounce operator depend on message

Tags: java, rx-java, reactive-programming, rx-java2

I study RxJava and try to understand how to implement non standard reactive "debouce" logic. Depend on message new operator must delay some kind of messages or skip it if another type of message arrives from observable.

[Debouce only A-messages or forget about it if another message arrived](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pCgEk.png)

Please help me compose this logic.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This requires a non-trivial combination of operators:

```java
public static <T> ObservableTransformer<T, T> debounceOnly(
        Predicate<? super T> condition, long time, 
        TimeUnit unit, Scheduler scheduler) {
    return o -> o.publish(f ->
        f.concatMapEager(v -> {
            if (condition.test(v)) {
                return Observable.just(v).delay(time, unit, scheduler).takeUntil(f);
            }
            return Observable.just(v);
        })
    );
}


@Test
public void test() {
    PublishSubject<String> subject = PublishSubject.create();

    TestScheduler sch = new TestScheduler();

    subject
    .compose(debounceOnly(v -> v.startsWith("A"), 
         100, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS, sch))
    .subscribe(System.out::println, Throwable::printStackTrace, 
         () -> System.out.println("Done"));

    subject.onNext("A1");

    sch.advanceTimeBy(100, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);

    subject.onNext("B1");
    sch.advanceTimeBy(1, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);

    subject.onNext("C1");
    sch.advanceTimeBy(1, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);

    subject.onNext("A2");
    sch.advanceTimeBy(50, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);

    subject.onNext("A3");
    sch.advanceTimeBy(100, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);

    subject.onNext("A4");
    sch.advanceTimeBy(50, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);

    subject.onNext("B2");
    sch.advanceTimeBy(100, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);

    subject.onNext("C2");
    sch.advanceTimeBy(100, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);

    subject.onComplete();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Kotlin code for RxJava 1.2.10:

```
val sequence = listOf(
            Pair(0, "A"),  // delay
            Pair(3, "B"),  // immediately
            Pair(4, "C"),  // immediately
            Pair(5, "A"),  // skip by next A
            Pair(6, "A"),  // delay
            Pair(9, "A"),  // skip by next B
            Pair(10, "B"), // immediately
            Pair(11, "C")  // immediately
    )

    val startTime = LocalDateTime.now()
    Observable
            .from(sequence)
            .flatMap { tm ->
                Observable.just(tm.second)
                        .delay(tm.first.toLong(), TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            }
            .compose { o ->
                o.publish { f ->
                    f.concatMap { v ->
                        if (v == "A")
                            Observable.just(v).delay(2, TimeUnit.SECONDS).takeUntil(f)
                        else
                            Observable.just(v)
                    }
                }
            }
            .toBlocking()
            .subscribe {
                        val currentTime = LocalDateTime.now()
                        val sec = currentTime.toEpochSecond(ZoneOffset.UTC) - startTime.toEpochSecond(ZoneOffset.UTC)
                        println("$sec - $it")
                    }
```